# Concerning the proof of an elementary proposition from John . F Humphrey's "A Course in Group Theory."

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Is the following argument Correct?

> Let $G$ be a group such that $g^2=1$ for all $g\in G$. Prove that $G$ is abelian.

*Proof.* Let $g\in G$ from the axiom of inverse we know that there exists a $g^{-1}\in G$ such that $gg^{-1} = 1$ in addition $g^2 = gg=1$ then by proposition **$3.3$** it follows that $g = g^{-1}$.

Now returning to our original proposition. Let $\alpha\in G$ and $\beta\in G$ from corollary **$3.4$** it follows that $(\alpha\beta)^{-1} = \beta^{-1}\alpha^{-1}$ but from our argument above it follows that $\alpha\beta = (\alpha\beta)^{-1}$ and $\beta^{-1}\alpha^{-1} = \beta\alpha$ implying $\alpha\beta = \beta\alpha$.

$\blacksquare$

**NOTE:**

> **Proposition $3.3$** Given a group $G$ and $a,b\in G$ there exists a unique solutions to the equation $ax=b$ and $ya=b$.
>
> **Proposition $3.4$** Given $a,b\in G$ we have $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: The argument is fine. The last few sentences could probably be better structed.

Comment: What's troubling you? The result "$g=g^{-1}$ **for all** $g\in G$" is applied to all of $g=\alpha\beta$, $g=\beta$ and $g=\alpha$ in turn.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct. The sentences need punctuation though.